# Out of stock message in ajax without page loading in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php

I am trying to show the out of stock message in Product details page without page loading. But by default, the message is showing after page load. I know how to add products to cart in ajx without page load, but out of stock message is only showing after page load. Kindly suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164755/magento2-ajax-add-to-cart-out-of-stock-situation-stop-redirect-and-show-me